# Next.js slow performance with static html exprt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

I have a simple one page app built with Next.js and mui. There's no real js dependency after page is rendered.

I want to export the app to a static html file using Next's feature [Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)

When I deploy the app regularly (e.g. with node js) the lighthouse performance score is 99. When I export the page to static html the score goes down to 80. The biggest problem is Total Blocking Time.

Because the web app is static, I edited the final HTML and deleted all script tags, so no javascript is loaded. 99% of the site still works fine (only one popover doesn't work) and now the performance score is 99.

Is there anything I can do to improve page load with static html? It feels like there should be some easy config to load the js in a way that will not block performance.

I tried changing all script tags to load async or defer and the score went up to 82, which I also found surprising because I'd expect defer to be similar to deleting the scripts when it comes to performance

[image: page performance]
[image]